# Batch Script that checks a directory for duplicate files

Tags: file, batch-file, duplicates, directory

Trying to look through a file for example,

> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\12345
>
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\45635
>
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\12345-2018-04-21

and create a subfolder named "12345" and will store the two files (12345 and 12345-2018-04-21) in subfolder "12345". and this will loop through the whole folder to make sure there is no copies

```
:: ---------------------------------------------------------------
:: - This is a program that searches for files with the same 5 
::   digit number and puts them in a subfolder.
:: ---------------------------------------------------------------
@ECHO off

SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test"
SET /a lastnum=200000

if "%first5%" equ "%lastnum%"(
SET "destdir=%destdir%\%first5%-sub"
 md %destdir%
)

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 CALL :detect "%%a"
 IF DEFINED dupnum (ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\")
)

GOTO end 

:: Routine to detect whether the first 5 characters of the filename "%1"
:: are all numeric and if so, whether they match the previous 5-digit number
:: found.

:detect
SET "dupnum="
:: Get the first 5 characters of the filename; prefix with a `1`
SET "fullfilename=%~1"
SET "first5=1%fullfilename:~0,5%"
IF "%first5%" neq "%lastnum%" (
 SET "lastnum=%first5%"
   GOTO end
)
:: First 5 chars of this filename = first 5 of previous filename
:: Check to see whether numeric
SET /a dummy=first5 + 0
IF "%dummy%" neq "%first5%" (
 SET "lastnum=%first5%"
   GOTO end 
)
SET "dupnum=Y"
   GOTO end 

ENDLOCAL

:end

PAUSE
```

Not sure why i can not get it to make a folder and store the duplicated files into it. It will read through my test folder and notice the duplicates and prompt to move them but i am not sure what i need to do to move it to a new folder.

Comment: Well you can't have the same file name twice in the same folder so I am not understanding what you mean by duplicate file.

Comment: let me clarify, sorry. they scan papers that puts a pdf of them into a folder on their server. if there is a copy it will add the date to the end of the name. so i need to check if the first 5 digits are the same.

Comment: The law firm names each file based on a random piece of information that gets them a 5 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine where to start if you've not encountered the language before.

The first issue is to properly specify what your terms mean. A "duplicate file" for instance would normally mean duplicate *contents* or a duplicate *name* (but since a directory can only hold one file with any particular name, this would imply different directories). In your case, your *individual* definition is "files whose names start with the same 5 digits".

Since this leads to a batch which uses many techniques (and there can be many approaches) then this is one that could be used:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET /a lastnum=200000

md %destdir% 2>nul

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 CALL :detect "%%a"
 IF DEFINED dupnum (ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\")
)

GOTO :EOF

:: Routine to detect whether the first 5 characters of the filename "%1"
:: are all numeric and if so, whether they match the previous 5-digit number
:: found.

:detect
SET "dupnum="
:: Get the first 5 characters of the filename; prefix with a `1`
SET "fullfilename=%~1"
SET "first5=1%fullfilename:~0,5%"
IF "%first5%" neq "%lastnum%" (
 SET "lastnum=%first5%"
 GOTO :eof
)
:: First 5 chars of this filename = first 5 of previous filename
:: Check to see whether numeric
SET /a dummy=first5 + 0
IF "%dummy%" neq "%first5%" (
 SET "lastnum=%first5%"
 GOTO :eof
)
SET "dupnum=Y"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Fundamentally, batch code is case-insensitive with the notable exception of the `metavariable` in a `for` statement (`%%a` above)

Batch is however quite layout-sensitive, so best to cut-and-paste rather than retyping and attempting to re-format to suite some more-pleasing-to-the-eye style.

It's normally assumed that batch code is run from the prompt, not by 'clicking'.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can normally be used "quoteless".

The `@echo off` statement turns command-echoing off so that the command is *not* echoed to the console before being executed.

The `setlocal` statement invokes a 'local environment' so that any alterations or additions to the environment are disposed of when the batch finishes.

The main loop first executes a `dir` command to produce a directory list. The options chosen are `/b` - basic (no header/footer - names only) `/a-d` - no directorynames and `/on` - order-by-name (ie alphabetical)

The output of the `dir` command is then processed by a `for /f` with the `"delims="` option. This assigns the *entire* line to the `metavariable` `%%a`.

For each filename found, the subroutine `:detect` is executed. Since that rouine is located within this batch file, a `:` is used in the `call` statement. Without the `:`, the routine `call`ed would be a batchfile named `detect` (either `detect.bat` or `detect.cmd`, the former being more popular)

After the routine `:detect` has been executed, a variable named `dupnum` may or may not be set. If it's set, `echo` the string. If not, don't.

The routine `:detect` first "set"s `dupnum` (the result of the routine) to an empty string, which removes the variable from the environment if it exists.

The variable `fullfilename` is then set to the value passed from the `call` statement. `%1` means "first parameter". `%~1` means "and remove enclosing quotes". The quotes are required to allow the filename being passed to contain spaces.

We then get the first 5 characters from the full filename (from "character 0" for 5 characters) and prefix this with a `1`. Batch regards a string which starts with a `0` as an *octal* string if used in a mathematical operation, so the `1` prefix ensures the now 6 characters are interpreted as decimal.

Now - if the `first5` is not equal to the `lastnum`, then we record the new `lastnum` and `goto :eof` which exits the subroutine. `dupnum` has not be set, so the calling loop will not show this filename.

Next, we only want to do the move if the first 5 (well, now 6) chars are all numeric. We can add `0` to the string in mathematical mode using a `set /a` which will either result in the same number (if these chars are all-numeric) or with a different number (up to the first non-numeric) if the "first5" contains a non-numeric.

So - test the result - if different, "first5" contains a non-numeric, so bail out with `dupnum` not set. If the same, then set `dupnum` so the filename is reported.

Please also note that the *official* remark instruction is `rem`, but `::` (which is a broken label - one which can't be reached) is often used instead for remarks as it is easier to type and less intrusive to the eye. Note however that the `::` style can't be used within `code-block`s (statements grouped between parentheses)

---

I've added a new line, `md ...` which should create the destination directory. The `2>nul` suppresses error messages should that directory already exist. If you want this directory to be a subdirectory of the source directory, then set `destdir` thus:

```
set "destdir=%sourcedir%\subdirectorynamedesired"
```

Comment: Appreciate it, man. Helps a lot. do you think i could complete the same task by making a c++  program? that is much easier for me to understand and code in.

Comment: I've tweaked you code slightly but i cannot get it to create a subfolder and through the files into it. It will echo that it is moving the files but not create a subfolder.